# How to concatenate lines of several associated files into one line, and append that to an output file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have several file named `BC**-tmp1.tsv` that are the first iteration of a blast output and other file named `BC**-tmp2.tsv`that are the second iteration.

Example of file `BC02-tmp1.tsv` (separator : `\t`) :

```
BC02    Aaa 2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    A
BC02    Bbb 2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    B
BC02    Ccc 2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    C
BC02    Ddd 2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    D
```

Example of file `BC02-tmp2.tsv` (separator : `\t`) :

```
BC02    Eee 2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    E
BC02    Fff 2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    F
BC02    Ggg 2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    G
BC02    Hhh 2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    H
```

My goal is to concatenate all those file by pair (iteration 1 + iteration 2) in a specific way.

Example of result with the example `BC02` in the final file:

```
BC02    Aaa 2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    A   B   C   BC02    Eee 2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    E   F   G
```

So to be more precise I want to print (on the same line) the first line of the `BC**-tmp1.tsv`file, then the last column of the second line, then the last column of the third line, then the first line of the `BC**-tmp2.tsv`file, then the last column of the second line, then the last column of the third line. And that for each pair of Barcodes.

**Note**: the second iteration file is not always present.

So far I managed to gather the associated files in a shell `for` loop, but I don't know how to do the rest:

```
touch template.tsv

for bla in *-tmp1.tsv; do
r="$(basename -s "-tmp1.tsv" $bla)"
awk 'FNR==1' $bla >> template.tsv
awk 'FNR==1' $r-tmp2.tsv >> template.tsv;
done
```

Do you know how to do that ?

---

**EDIT simpler input/output:**

Input:

```
$ head BC02-tmp*.tsv
==> BC02-tmp1.tsv <==
a       b       B
a       c       C
a       d       D
a       e       E

==> BC02-tmp2.tsv <==
a       w       W
a       x       X
a       y       Y
a       z       Z
```

Output:

```
a       b       B       C       D       a       w       W       X       Y
```

Comment: then what does those fourth line in your input files do? also I answered to your previous question which it does print those words (first and second words of the second column) with Tab separated means in two separate columns (Tab is delimiter), but here I see you used those pair of words as single column,just wanted to tell you if you want then (two words) to considered as single column instead of two, use there `print $0, tmp[1] " " tmp[2]`.

Comment: @αғsнιη Thanks for the update on my last topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your input doesn't contain fringe cases, the following shell loop in connection to an `awk` program should do:

```bash
for f in BC*-tmp1.tsv
do
    f2="${f/%tmp1.tsv/tmp2.tsv}"
    if [[ ! -f $f2 ]]; then f2=""; fi
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
         FNR==1{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) printf "%s%s",(NR==FNR&&i==1?"":OFS),$i}
         FNR<=3{printf "%s%s",OFS,$NF}
         END{printf "%s",ORS}' "$f" "$f2" >> template.tsv
done
```

This will loop over all `tmp1.tsv` files and generate the corresponding filename for the `tmp2.tsv` file. If the second file turns out not to exist, the filename will be set to the empty string.

It will then call an `awk` program with both associate TSV files, which will print - all on the same line

- all fields, excluding the last one, of the first line of each input file (but preceded by an additional OFS in case of the second input file, characterized by `FNR`, the per-file line counter, no longer being equal to `NR`, the global line counter),
- the last field of each line until line 3,
- when no input file remains, a closing record separator (defaults to newline)

and appends the output to `template.tsv`. This will also work if the second template file doesn't exist, because the empty string token will not be recognized as input file by `awk` in the first place, so the `END` section printing the newline will be reached after the first file already.